# Linux mint and Atollic

Tags: linux

Hi to all i use a linux mint ver. 19.0 (tara), all work well now i want use Attolic Truestudio, i installa it and all work well. I create a simple project for STM32F401RE Nucleo and i put in usb, if i digit lsusb i see this:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 046d:c402 Logitech, Inc. Marble Mouse (2-button)
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 174f:14b8 Syntek 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0483:374b STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2.1 (Nucleo-F103RB)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

when i compile i don't have problem but if i debug the project i see this error:

```
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] File doesn't exist, wait 10 ms and try again
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb couldn't open USB device 
/dev/bus/usb/003/000: No such file or directory
 ST-Link enumeration failed
 Error in initializing ST-Link device.
 Reason: ST-Link DLL error.
```

also have this problem with administrative privileges, can you help me? excuse me for my bad english
best regards.
A.

Comment: Let's think about the errors you receive. What do you suppose `File doesn't exist` means? Or how about `No such file or directory`? It looks like in your code, which you haven't shared with us, it is trying to get information from `Bus 003 Device 000` which isn't being recognized by `lsusb`. How are you supposed to get information from a device that doesn't exist or not recognized by your Linux device?

Comment: First, you should never run tools like this as root; use a udev rule to grant access to the device node.  If you look at the instructions for a more linux centric package like https://github.com/texane/stlink you'll see how to set that up, it might also be worth trying that tool as a cross check on the hardware situation.  Next it's a bit unclear why this program is trying to access an invalid looking USB device node name - they seem to count from 001 not 000, and it looks like your actual device should have been /dev/bus/usb/003/006 something you could check with `ls -l /dev/bus/usb/003/006`